# Stop CKEditor removing Facebook Like Box code

Tags: javascript, facebook, configuration, ckeditor

I'm trying to paste standard Facebook's *Like Box* code into source view of CKEditor. But switching back to WYSIWYG mode and back to source view removes all the code. Of course the same happens when opening already saved content.

```
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers" data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="true" data-header="true" data-stream="false" data-show-border="true"></div>
```

It occurs when you paste this code into official demo, too - http://ckeditor.com/demo

Seems like it's related to empty tags and non-standard attributes.

Is there any way to prevent this editor from stealing page content?

Playground on JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/eKZvv/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about the [Advanced Content Filter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter). There are plenty of options including disabling it and extending its settings. For example:

```
config.extraAllowedContent = 'div(!fb-like-box)[data-*]';
```

Note: the above code requires CKEditor 4.4+. In previous versions the code should look a little bit differently, because there was no wildcards support then.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I used above code on http://jsfiddle.net/eKZvv/1/ but it doesn't help at all. I tried disabling Advanced Content Filter earlier, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Update: seems that it helped a bit. Now, with that config entry, it's being removed only when it's used alone. Writing any characters before or after the tag leaves the code with no harm. Any idea?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure in this case, because the difference between "used alone" and "surrounded by content" is odd, but I think that it's the same reason as usual. Empty elements have no meaning for editor and thus might be removed. Keep in mind that this isn't a website builder but content editor. For purposes like this one the [Widget System](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/widget_sdk_intro) has been created. PS. Note that in your case putting a `&nbsp;` or whatever else will be perhaps the easiest solution.